mounting multiple routes on a FastAPI app results in 404 not found error
I am building a Chainlit application with a custom react front-end. I am using the latest version of Chainlit which allows mounting chainlit as an app on its own. I am then mounting my custom react front-end on a separate path using StaticFiles as below
app = FastAPI()
mount_chainlit(app=app, target="cl_app.py", path="/chainlit")
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="../frontend/dist/", html=True), name="app")

With the above code, I am able to navigate to the /chainlit route to render the chainlit application mounted on that route but if I navigate to the root path /, I get a 404.
If I swap the other in which these routes are defined as below
app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="../frontend/dist/", html=True), name="app")
mount_chainlit(app=app, target="cl_app.py", path="/chainlit")

then the / works and perfectly renders my custom react front-end but then /chainlit results in 404 not found.
So my observation is that whatever route I configure last fails to be found. I suspect that using / for the react front-end might be causing some issues somewhere but not sure where or what.

It seems like chainlit mounts it's app on / regardless of what you give in path - it just means that internally in chainlit that's where it will be handled: https://github.com/Chainlit/chainlit/blob/7dbdbc587b2f3eba8aade6c28bd2a484e35aed78/backend/chainlit/utils.py#L117 - you can make your own version of this function and try to replace the path given to the mount function yourself

Does this or this answer your question?

@MatsLindh I will look into that but with my current setup, I invoke the chainlit endpoints on /chainlit path and not on / which tells me it is probably mounted on /chainlit path

You can see it yourself in the code I linked - path is not considered for where the application itself gets mounted: app.mount("/", chainlit_app) - this should be app.mount(f"{path}", chainlit_app) if they actually used the path for mounting the app. So what they're saying is that the chainlit app should handle any requests under / for that given app, which conflicts with the StaticFiles app you're trying to register as well.

@MatsLindh you are right and based on that I have concluded that the only way to make this possible is to not mount my react app on the root path as that is taken by chainlit already. This is not what I wanted but have to live with that until they fix it.

Or you can just copy that function and make the modification yourself (it's not many lines), then report an issue (and submit a PR with your own fix) and keep track of it - and update it when it gets fixed. That way you'll avoid having to switch everything around later again as necessary

The related github issue:  https://github.com/Chainlit/chainlit/issues/1166
